# how to compare all vector indexes with a constant value and switch the value of another variable (0 1) based on that

Tags: matlab, for-loop, if-statement, comparison

I have a 1x24 vector (a). I should define a command in Matlab which compare all 24 values of a vector (a) with a certain value (mean (b)) and if the vector (a) item is greater than certain value (mean (b)), ''I'' sets 1 and if the vector item is less than certain value ''I'' sets 0. I wrote the below code:

```
for i=1:length(a)
if a(i) >= mean(b)
I = 1;
else
I = 0;
end
end
```

But it implements the comparison only for the last index of vector a and sets I=0. How can I fix the command that do the comparison for all indexes of vector a?

Answer (score 2):

In MATLAB, you can use the following syntax to do so:

```
I = a >= mean(b);
```

If you want to use your code for doing so, you'll need to initialize I as a vector, and modify its indices as follows:

```
I = zeros(length(a),1)
for ii=1:length(a)
    if a(ii) >= mean(b)
        I(ii) = 1;
    else
        I(ii) = 0;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read about [logical indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) in matlab. You don't need for loops for what you are doing. For example, if you have,

```
rng(5);
a = rand(1,10);
b = 0.5;
```

then, `I = a > b;` will return a logical array with zeros and ones, where one indicates the position in the array where the given condition is satisfied,

```
I =

     0     1     0     1     0     1     1     1     0     0
```

Using these indices, you can modify your original array. For example, if you wish to change all values of `a` greater than `b` to be 10, you would simply do,

```
a(a > b) = 10;
```

Specifically, if you need indices where the condition is satisfied, you can use, `find(a > b)`, which in this example will give you,

```
ans =

     2     4     6     7     8
```